# Getting error on 2nd line in code below..What could be wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (I = 0; I < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; I++)
{
 if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsDefault"].ToString()) == true && Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsBill"].ToString()) == true)
.
.
.
.
```

Error: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Is default and IsBill are boolean values only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some values are null in your table.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsDefault"] != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsBill"]) != null)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsDefault"].ToString()) == true && Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsBill"]..ToString()) == true)
        {


        }

    }
```

You might have to use Convert.IsDBNull function to check whether the value is NULL.

Comment: I did like u said..now it says "System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Comment: I changed like u said..still gave me the error "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean." There were only 4 records in my table with IsDEfault value as null..I deleted those rows and the error vanished..Why did it gave error even after adding that condition to check if IsDefault is !=null ?

Comment: I think you should use `Convert.IsDBNull` function to check whether a field is null or not. Please try using that function and let me know whether it works so I can update my answer :)

Comment: The other option to think about @Serenity is what is causing this issue... you have a boolean with 3 possible states - true, false and null. You either need to convert this into a `bool?' or write some code (most likely using `Convert.IsDBNull`) that specifies if nulls in your database should be viewed as true or false

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you aren't too comfortable with some of the debugging tools that are available in Visual Studio.

In future, if you wanted to figure this out yourself, I can suggest a couple of debugging methods:

1) Put a breakpoint in at that line and then mousing over the .ToString() method to see what it is returning
2) When you are at the breakpoint, click on the tab that says "immediate window", and then type the call that might be returning something odd, in this case
`ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsDefault"].ToString()`
You can then see the result that is being returned by your call and you'll most likely solve your own bugs!

Edit: I was wrong about the cause, but I'd think a suggestion on good debugging practice is worthwhile! Good luck!

Comment: Quick question, why the minus?

Comment: Agreed. If somebody gives a vote down, they should atleast specify why they're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Something can be improved in your code.

(1) Usually we use a lower case variable `i` in the loop.

(2) Don't use column names directly in your code. Suppose some day, the column name is changed from "isDefault" to "DefaultOrNot"(just an example), it's a nightmare because you need to modify the strings everywhere in your code. An enum is helpful here.

```
enum TableColumns //well, it's a bad name
{
   ID = 0,
   Name = 1,
   IsDefault = 2   
}
```

and visit your table cell with `table.Rows[0][(int)TableColumns.IsDefault]`. You need to modify the `enum` only if any columns are added or changed.

(3) I think the format exception is because of that the cell's value is `T/F` instead of `True/False`. So converting it to `bool` type will cause a format exception.

(4) You'd better to check if there is an value in this cell before using it.

EDIT: Are you storing the value in DB with `1/0` (1 for true and 0 for false)? So you should use:

```
object cell = table.Rows[0]["IsDefault"];
if (cell != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(cell))
{
    if (cell.ToString().Equals("1"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of IsDefault and IsBill columns in your DB, if you can. Do you have a bit column for them? If yes then it might be returning 1 or 0 and you may be trying to convert them into boolean which is not so easily done.

Also, check for null. The FormatException comes when the value you're trying to convert can't possibly be converted on the target type.

**UPDATE:
I think you've got the parenthesis wrong here. Your if is ending immediately after the first ToString()**

**if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsDefault"].ToString())** == true && Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[I]["IsBill"].ToString()) == true)

Comment: well they are of bit type only

Comment: Plz check my comment under first answer above..thnx

Comment: @Serenity: You should update your question if you have any new information. Not everyone will go through all answers.

Comment: @Serenity If you've a bit field you can't apply ToString to it directly to check for a boolean value. You should put an if which checks whether the value is 1 or 0 instead of true or false.